# Maven target a certain architecture and platform

Tags: java, maven

Certain Maven repositories contain platform and architecture specific JARs. Is there a way to specify this in my POM file, so that I don't download unnecessary files from the Maven repo?

E.g. leptonica, mkl, openblas, opencv

Comment: You can have build profiles that are activated depending on the OS. I am not sure whether this what you are looking for.

Comment: @JFMeier I'm looking more to stop Maven from downloading and bundling JARs from other platforms, since I've noticed linux, android, mac JARs being downloaded, even though the dev machine is Windows.

Comment: You can put Maven dependencies into profiles that are only activated on special OS.

Comment: @JFMeier Could you elaborate how to configure a dependency to only download Windows or platform-agnostic JARs?

Answer (score 0):

Following

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

you can write

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <name>Windows XP</name>
        <family>Windows</family>
        <arch>x86</arch>
        <version>5.1.2600</version>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.x</groupId>
         <artifactId>something</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

The `<activation>` allows you to include the dependency only when the operating system fulfils certain criteria.

Comment: Is it possible to specify I want the Windows version of the `something-1.2.3` artifact?

Comment: So how is the Windows version marked? Does it have a classifier? Or a special suffix in the version or artifactId?

Comment: There's a suffix for [openblas](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/openblas/0.3.5-1.4.4), e.g. `openblas-0.3.5-1.4.4-windows-x86.jar`

Comment: This looks like a classifier. Then you have to add `<classifier>windows-x86</classifier>` to the dependency definition. It may also be part of the version number, then you would need to change the version to `0.3.5-1.4.4-windows-x86`.